# Swagger-Codegen generate clients in multiple languages

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I am currently trying to create Swagger clients using the Swagger-Codegen for multiple languages. Everything is fine for a single language, but when doing it for multiple languages the complexity seems to increase unnecessarily.

Some of the options in my config.json file are not supported/available in other languages and therefore I would have to create a config file for every language, which makes it for example ridiculous complex to do a version bumb. So my current approach would be to write a script that calls the Swagger-Codegen several times passing different config parameters per language. However, this seems more like a hack than a solution, so I was wondering if I missed anything in the docs or if any of you came up with a better solution?

Comment: I would suggestion to start a discussion in Swagger Codegen Github repo instead: http://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: @wing328, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't want to open an issue straight away. Will do that now :).

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4601